# Create dynamic user filter view in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, filter

I have a lead table that contains data which also contains information which user has entered this data. Now I want to create a filter that when selecting a particular user only his data is displayed. How to do this in **cakephp**. Please help.

Thanks in advance

User database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

lead table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leads` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `board_number` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'board number',
  `mobile_number` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'mobile number',
  `requirements` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_price_quoted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'total price quoted',
  `our_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'our price',
  `margin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closing_month` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'closing month',
  `probablity` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;
```

Controller Code LeadController.php

```
public function user_filter() {      
    //$this->render('filter');        
    $this->loadModel('User');        
    $this->User->recursive = 0;

    $userFilter = $this->User->find('all',array(
        'fields' => array('User.username')
    ));

    $this->set('userFilter', $userFilter);

    return $userFilter;  
}
```

// View/filterMenu.ctp
//here a dropdown menu of listed user

```
<?php
    $userFilters  = $this->requestAction(
        array(
            'controller' => 'leads',
            'action' => 'user_filter'
        )
    ); 
?>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php foreach ($userFilters as $userFilter): ?>
        <li>
            <?php  
                echo $this->Html->link($userFilter['User']['username'],array(
                    'controller'=>'leads',
                    'action'=>'user_filter'
                )); 
                echo "<\n>";
           ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>
</ul
```

I want to create view of that particular user.

Comment: Please provide the database structure that you are using along with some sort of code that you implemented till yet.

Comment: this is the code i have impemented yet. I want to pass the user id as pass argument and generate the view of that user dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you cannot provide links through dropdown, you must use javascript to direct to page.

to display all the leads from particular user, pass the user id to the function and fetch data using user id.

```
public function user_filter($id = null) { 
    if ($id){
       $leads = $this->Lead->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Lead.user_id' => $id)));
    }else{
      $leads = $this->Lead->find('all');
    }

    $this->loadModel('User');        
    $this->User->recursive = 0;

    $userFilter = $this->User->find('all',array(
        'fields' => array('User.username')
    ));
    $this->set('leads', $leads);
    $this->set('userFilter', $userFilter);

    return $userFilter;  
}
```

Hope this will help you.